# Borsuk-Ulam Theorem for torus.

Tags: algebraic-topology

Is the Borsuk-Ulam theorem valid for a torus? In other words, for any map $f: S^1 \times S^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{R^2}$ there is a point $(x,y) \in S^1 \times S^1$ which $f(x,y)=f(-x,-y)$

I'm very stuck on this task. 
Can someone give a hint? Or there can be a detailed solution, if suddenly this task is easy enough.

Thank you in advance for help!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

No. With the usual torus embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$, lying on the $OXY$ plane, one has a natural projection onto that plane, $p:S^1×S^1\to \mathbb{R}^2$, which is continuous.

Two points on the torus have the same image if they are one above the other, 
in the same vertical line. In particular, they are in the same meridian of
the torus, i.e. they have the same first coordinate. So, if $p(a,b) = p(c,d)$,
$a = c$. This implies that the Borsuk-Ulam theorem fails on the torus because if $x=-x$, and then $x=0\notin S^1$.

Comment: Could you, please, be more explicit - what "natural projection" are you talking about? UPD: Ah, I think I got it: you mean $S^1\times S^1$ embedded as a usual 3D torus into $\mathbb R^3$, and the projection goes onto the plane parallel to the big circle of the torus. It would help to mention this explicitly, I think.

Comment: Thank you very much! Very simple and intuitive solution I like it.

Comment: Yes, with the usual torus embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$,  lying on the $OXY$ plane, $p$ is just the projection onto that plane. I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: Way easier than the answer I was cooking up (and then abandoned).  +1

Comment: What do you mean by $x\not\in S^1$? Is the circle a line segment with ends attached, or a subset of $\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: @mr_e_man $S^1$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ or $\mathbb{C}$. In any definition of $S^1$ where $-x$ means the antipodal of $x$, $x\neq -x$ for all $x\in S^1$. I just took advantage of the notation $-x$ to use it as the opposite point.

Comment: I was thinking $S^1 = \mathbb R^1/(x+1\sim x)$, in which $-x = 1-x$. Then $\frac12 = -\frac12$, and $0=1$. The other definition that you use is valid, though it wasn't mentioned in the OP.

Comment: @mr_e_man that's right, I'll edit it to make it more general

Comment: My mistake; I wasn't familiar with the Borsuk-Ulam Theorem, which does specify that $-x$ is the antipodal point, not an opposite in $\mathbb R^1/(x+1\sim x)$.... I think the answer was better before the edit.

Comment: @Javi: Can we also prove by finding 3 closed sets  whose union is the torus and none of which contains a pair of antipodal points? Since any subspace in $\mathbb R^3$ satisfying Borsuk-Ulam theorem must also satisfy this property?

Comment: @WilliamLeynoid What is the Borsuk-Ulam theorem for an arbitrary subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: @Javi: I mean the property that " for any continuous map from the space $X$ to $\mathbb R^2$, there is a pair of antipodal points taking the same value". For any space satisfing this property, we can apply it to the distance map for the three closed sets cover $X$.

Comment: @WilliamLeynoid but the point is that the torus does not satisfy that property. And I don't really understand what you get out of covering the spaces with three closed subset with no antipodal points. Are you implying that because on each subset there are not antipodal points the function cannot reach the same value on antipodal points?

Comment: @Javi: Yes, the torus dosn't satisfies that property, and I mean we can prove it by contradiction. Assume the torus satisfies the property that "*for any continuous map from the space $T$ to $\mathbb R^2$, there is a pair of antipodal points taking the same value*", we show that if $A_1,A_2,A_3$ are closed sets cover $T$, one of them have a pair of antipodal points. Let $d_j(x)=d(x,A_j)$, then $(d_1,d_2)$ takes the same value at some $x,-x$, hence $d(x,A_1)=d(-x,A_1), d(x,A_2)=d(-x,A_2)$. If one of them is $0$, we are done. If both are positive then $x$ and $-x$ must contains in $A_3$.

Comment: Since such closed covering $A_1,A_2,A_3$ clearly exist for $T$, it cannot satisfies that property!

Comment: @WilliamLeynoid I see, that's interesting. Maybe not so appealing for some people as it is non-constructive and probably more complex than a simple counterexample. But it's cool.