# why $x=0 \notin S^1 ?$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, algebraic-topology

I have some confusion on this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2812403/557708)

> Here is the  outline of the  solution

> No. With the usual torus embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$, lying on the $OXY$ plane, one has a natural projection onto that plane, $p:S^1×S^1\to \mathbb{R}^2$, which is continuous.

> Two points on the torus have the same image if they are one above the other,
> in the same vertical line. In particular, they are in the same meridian of
> the torus, i.e. they have the same first coordinate. So, if $p(a,b) = p(c,d)$,
> $a = c$. This implies that the Borsuk-Ulam theorem fails on the torus because if $x=-x$, and **then** $x=0\notin S^1$.

**My confusion** :   why $x=0 \notin S^1  ?$

My thinking : $S^1 =\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2  +y^2 =1\}$

Now put $x=0$,then $\{(0,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : 0^2  +y^2 =1\} \implies  y=1$

I think $x=0  \in S^1$

Comment: $x$ is a real number, not an element of $\mathbb R^2$. You showed that $(0,1) \in S^1$.

Comment: 0 is the zero vector here.

Comment: @КряжевАрсений                        that means $x=(0,0) $  Am i right ?

Comment: @jasmine    Right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you work in several dimensions, it is usual to denote by $x\in\mathbb R^d$ the vector instead of the first coordinate. For example writing in dimension $2$
$$
x = (x_1,x_2), \ \text{ and } \ 0 = (0,0).
$$
Hence if $x=0$, then $|x| = 0 \neq 1$ so $x\notin \mathbb S^1$.

Answer (score 0):

This question is about an answer of mine, and while the accepted answer is correct, there is another interpretation, which is seeing $S^1$ as a subspace of the complex numbers. Since $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ are homeomorphic, there is no difference, topologically speaking, but now $0$ is literally the complex number $0$. This is actually the interpretation that I had in mind.